# Set up direct SSH connection from A to C without public IPs using one public SSH server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I have available these SSH servers/clients:

> A - without public IP
>
> B - public IP
>
> C - without public IP

I know, I can establish an SSH connection from A to C as follows:

1) Hook C to B. Doing from C:

> `ssh -R 10100:localhost:22 B_IP`

2) Set port forwarding from A to C using B hook in order to be able of ssh-agent usage on machine A:

> `ssh -L 5000:localhost:10100 B_IP`

3) Now I can use my ssh keys to "directly" access C from A:

> `ssh -p 5000 localhost`

... my point is:

**Can I somehow establish new "pure" connection from A to C** so that after machine B goes down, I can continue my work?

I think it should be possible as long, as these two computers realise, they already share a connection, or am I wrong?

Thanks for your time & ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The *usual* method is to set up "NAT port forwarding" on A's or C's router. (How it's done depends on router, but there are instructions everywhere.) Once you do that, you can connect to C-router's public address + the "forwarded" port, and the connection will go through to C.

  (Note: NAT port-forwarding and SSH port-forwarding are similar *but distinct* things, like a hammer and a screwdriver. Do not confuse them.)
- If you do not have administrative access to either router, you could try using UPnP or NAT-PMP to set up a port forwarding rule, as many games and P2P programs do. For this, use `upnpc` or `natpmpc` commands.
- If neither of above methods work, you will need some form of [NAT hole-punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)). (See also the [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) and [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_hole_punching) hole-punching articles.)

  Unfortunately, while it's widely used in various *specific* programs, there don't seem to be many *generic* tools for TCP, though **[chownat](http://samy.pl/chownat/)** may work.

Comment: Well, first solution was already obvious to me, but I don't have public IP on my router ... about the second solution - I'm now about to try it out, so I'll report it back - but I'd like to make something clear to me - is it possible to communicate from A to C using UPnP or NAT-PMP without any public server I have access to ?... and honestly the third solutions seems the most attractive to me, so I can't wait to try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably impossible unless you can do some kind of port forwarding on the routers - but in this case you don't need computer C at all.

The thing is that in your example you are not going directly from A -> C, the packets are all still traversing B.

If you have another computer with public addresses on it, you can probably set up a VPN setup in a star topography, and use routing between the VPN's to create a virtual network where either of the public hosts can fall over and things can continue to work.  I've done this with OpenVPN - there are a few gotchas - one important one being disabling Reverse Path Filtering.

Comment: It's technically possible, if both hosts can cooperate (e.g. by using STUN, or perhaps using lesser-known TCP features).

Comment: @grawity - I thought about that initially, however this still requires a connection to the external address of the other device which requires port-forwarding.  (I'm suspect you know STUN is a way of exposing a public IP address from behind NAT).  The thing is that as the IP address is changing between NAT and non-NAT I don't see how an SSH client can continue to allow a connection as it would be a security risk [ ie a MITM could take over the connection more easily ], and surely the TCP session must die also.   Thats the reason I came up with a VPN based solution...cont

Comment: Thats the reason I postulated a VPN based solution - it abstracts the IP address and allows routing across a virtual connection - but unless you can get the VPN pinholed or running on the routers you still have the problem of how the VPN endpoints can see each other.  It might be possible to allow VPN endpoints to "float" and not check the actual underlying IP addresses, but you would still need to get the pinholing working to detect the session mid-way, and I can think of no way to do that.

Comment: Ah yes, I mistook SIP's NAT traversal features as being part of STUN.

Comment: Well, thanks for your nice workaround, but still - let's assume I want to have established an connection between A & C even after all my public servers available goes down - your solution does not appear to match this condition to me

Comment: @jirislav - Can't be done with conventional IPV4 equipment.  (Read my discussion with Grawity for my machinations as to why)

Comment: @davidgo - I'm not sure I understood you solution - you suppose to create VPN servers on each A, B & C right? Then somehow create direct route from A to C so that B can go down right? Will this work even if A & B are behind NATs ?

Comment: No. There is no answer that will let you communicate between a and c over ssh without a publicly reachable endpoint to route traffic through unless you can make changes to the routers (eg run vpns on them or possibly port forwarding) or a and c are in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that would be to use a peer to peer VPN - a VPN that doesn't require one of the hosts to have a static IP address or a static domain name pointing to it. Other ideas mentioned below are not really VPNs, but are software that establishes a peer to peer connection via some kind of a protocol. Here are some options:

###### Based on [tox.chat](https://tox.chat) network:

I personally tried both solutions, but they got blocked by my work's (big corporate style) network.

- [toxvpn](https://github.com/cleverca22/toxvpn) - not seems very well maintained as of today, but should work.
- [tuntox](https://github.com/gjedeer/tuntox) - Similar idea, though it's not a real VPN, but can make a connection and forward ssh ports between two machines on the tox network. Examples for ssh are available in the README.

###### Based on public, non-free chat services

Haven't tried any of these personally, and I doubt they will work, but they may be worth trying.

- [LAN party VPN](https://github.com/gyf304/lpvpn) - Based on Discord. Not seems very well maintained as of today, also README doesn't include many examples but perhaps it'd be worth checking.
- [robotito](https://github.com/formigarafa/robotito) - not seems very well maintained. Also installation seems hard - uses [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com/about) (formerly GTalk).

###### VPNs based on a public server (maintained by others)

Personal experience: tried `n2n`, but it got blocked by my work's (big corporate style) network.

- [n2n](https://github.com/ntop/n2n) - uses a "*supernode*" that is maintained by the [ntop](https://www.ntop.org) team - it is operating according `n2n`'s README at `supernode.ntop.org:7777` (the supernode is also free software, but running it requires again, a publicly accessible server).
- [Nubela](https://nebula.defined.net/docs/) - Similar concept like `n2n`, but instead of *supernode* it's called a *lighthouse*. They don't offer a publicly lighthouse for everyone to use, but you actually have to run their `dnclient` on your publicly available VPS as explained in [their docs](https://docs.defined.net/guides/enrolling-a-lighthouse/). Hence it doesn't answer your requirements but I thought it'd be still worth mentioning.

###### Other VPN solutions which require a paid subscription.

Unlike most commercial VPN services out there, only few of them target power users will allow two users to communicate with each other over the VPN's subnets you get. It's likely there are other providers available there that can provide this functionality. Here is one:

- [Hamachi, by LogmeIn (vpn.net)](https://vpn.net/) - Client is not open source, but seems [according to their docs](https://support.logmeininc.com/hamachi/help/the-logmein-hamachi-client-hamachi-c-hamachi-aboutclients) that indeed it let's you manage the network and IP addresses etc.

###### Based on community maintained networks

Even behind a heavy NAT, if your firewall is not too restrictive (not true in my case) you may be able to do either of the following (not VPNs):

- [tor](https://torproject.org/) - Try [this guide](https://medium.com/@tzhenghao/how-to-ssh-over-tor-onion-service-c6d06194147). Basically, you are creating a `.onion` domain (tor service) that tor users from all over the world can access.
- [i2pd](https://i2pd.website/) - Try [this guide](https://geti2p.net/en/blog/post/2019/06/15/i2p-i2pd-ssh-config) which also have instructions for `i2dp` - the `i2p` client I'd recommend.

###### Last resort solution

Even with the most annoying firewalls, NAT and other network restrictions you may be subject to, you should be able to use wonderful https://tmate.io/ free (as in free beer and as in free speech) software and service. However it has some drawbacks:

- No interactive commands (see [issue #179](https://github.com/tmate-io/tmate/issues/179)).
- No `scp` support.
- `tmux` version from which the fork is based on is as of today `2.6.0`, while current tmux latest version is `3.3a` - this means that for your `~/.tmux.conf` to work as `~/.tmate.conf`, you'll have to make non-trivial adjustments (see [e.g from my personal dotfiles](https://github.com/doronbehar/.tmux/compare/33e9a5a10b66139c30c04f1ebb77ec985bf89254..83cec6850f6461d78102347a667e4125bc5c6a0f)).

Although tmate's maintainers don't mention this explicitly, I think the 1st two drawbacks mentioned are intentional restrictions, as people can abuse these abilities to transfer loads of data over `tmate.io`'s server. Hence this makes `tmate` really a sort of "remote desktop" for your shell. You'll have to find other methods to transfer files between the two machines (consider [syncthing](https://syncthing.net)).

Altogether - the ease of use of tmate, and it's wonderful performance makes it the best solution IMO. Coupled with [syncthing](https://syncthing.net) for transferring files, I think it's the best solution and most reliable one.